# Three.js multiple renderers prevent textgeometry from custom positioning

Tags: three.js

http://jsfiddle.net/wk8f9/

If I comment out the first renderer in the render function, the text can be positioned wherever I want it to be positioned.
but if I leave both of the function calls in then only the first renderer's text can be positioned using object.position.set.

The issue is only with textgeometry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to reuse pointtext material near the top of my code but three.js doesn't allow the recycling of materials/geometries.. I failed to catch that one line of code that messed everything up.